# How to create multi panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create two panels in asp.net with images on boxes in one panel. When we click image box with colour that same colour should be applied in the other panel with data from that clicked box

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx).
When you now use the [ImageButton.OnClick event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx), you are getting the [ImageClickEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.imageclickeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Grab the X-, and Y-Coords and get the pixel of the image at this location.